# Why does boron add to the less substituted carbon in the hydroboration of an alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, regioselectivity, c-c-addition, organoboron-compounds

In the hydroboration of a typical alkene, the boron fragment ends up attached to the less substituted carbon:

[image: Hydroboration of an alkene]

What are the electronic or steric factors that lead to this regioselectivity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the hydroboration of isobutene

[image]

there is a steric aspect:

[image: sterics]

And though sterics may play some part, it doesn't explain near 100% regioselectivity. More important in determining regiochemistry, I would say, are the electronics of the transition state:

[image: electronics]

Boron is electrophilic, and as such will draw the electron density of the alkene π-bond towards itself. This C–B bond formation occurs earlier than the C–H bond formation, which in turn imparts a partial positive charge to the other carbon of the double bond in the transition state of the reaction.

This somewhat resembles a carbocation, which you might remember are stabilized by additional substituents via [hyperconjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconjugation). Thus, hydroboration results in an anti-Markovnikov product for mostly the same reason that acid catalyzed hydration results in a Markovnikov product — stabilization of positive charge.

Comment: How boron will draw the electron density of the alkene π-bond towards itself while carbon is more electronegative than it?

Comment: It is a Lewis acid.

Comment: Why C-B bond forms faster ?

Comment: How can hyperconjugation explain stability of partial charges.? There is no p orbital on carbon to hyperconjugate

Comment: Hyperconjugation doesn't need to go into a *pure* p orbital, it works with *any* kind of orbital that isn't full, as long as there is sufficient overlap.