# How does hyperconjugation explain stability of partial positive charges?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, molecular-orbital-theory, resonance, hyperconjugation

Recently I was reading [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/69049/41328) to the question [Why does boron add to the less substituted carbon in the hydroboration of an alkene?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/69042/76375).
See the transition state given in the above answer, and the reason given to explain it's stability.

As far as I know, hyperconjugation is a result of σ-p interaction in carbocations.
If partial charges are developed(as in the case of linked answer), there is no empty p orbital in them.

So how can hyperconjugation be used to explain their stability?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is referring to the partial positive charge on the carbon opposite the developing C-B bond. It is stabilized by substituents similar to how a full carbocation is stabilized by substituents, e.g., in the tert-butyl carbocation. This doesn't need to be a completely empty p-orbital—electron density will be dynamically influenced by any imbalance in charge distribution—but if it's easier to conceptualize, you could imagine it as the pi-bond electrons being fully transferred to the C-B bond, leaving an empty p-orbital on the opposite carbon, which is stabilized by hyperconjugation.

The reality should be closer to a dynamic process at both sites, though. The pi-bond transfers electron density into the C-B bond, while the substituents stabilize the rising positive charge on the other carbon. As the C-B bond develops, the B-H bond simultaneously weakens, and begins moving its electron density toward the partial-positive carbon.